# Css image absolute position on top of responsive image

Tags: html, css, image

How do I keep the balloon image position stick to the grid image as you resize it?

Balloon1 and B2 are actually inside grid 5 and 7 but if you resize left right, the Balloons will offside.

Do I need a special calc or javascript / jquery library for that?

Thanks.

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/archie_lee/h94ou58b/)

```css
.container{
  max-width:600px;
  max-height:400px;
}
.image-container{
  width:70%;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
}
.img-grid{
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
.balloon{
  position:absolute;
  left:30%;
  top:50%;
}
.balloon2{
  position:absolute;
  left:60%;
  top:15%;
}
```

```html
Resize this area
<div class= "container">
  <div class="image-container">
       <img class="img-grid" src="https://image.ibb.co/hFUHdz/example18.png" />
       
       <img class="balloon" src="https://image.ibb.co/b445WK/tkp_5_balloonpop.png"/>
       <img class="balloon2" src="https://image.ibb.co/b445WK/tkp_5_balloonpop.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="text-container">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this is expected. In order to align them correctly you would need to decrease size of the balloons when image gets smaller.

Comment: how to resize the balloon in respect to the grid image decrease in size?

Comment: Here is an example: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dgcha (width of the ballons in %)

Comment: @max, what if there is a fixed height to the container, my web app actually set a full screen fix width and height (slick slider carausel), so I am having difficulty facing responsive height, I updated my fiddle

Comment: I don't see a problem when I set widths in percentages in that fiddle

Comment: Ok I think I know what you mean and I'm afraid you can't achieve your goal without using JS. If you can make a fiddle with that slider.

Comment: Done, updated fiddle with slick slider

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177415/discussion-between-max-and-ardeus).

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries at say four points throughout the resize, i.e.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
img{width:60%;height:auto;}
}
```

Just play about with the image width.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decrease size of the balloons when image gets smaller.

In order to do that you can set ballons width in percentages.

```css
.container{
  max-width:600px;
  max-height:400px;
}
.image-container{
  width:70%;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
}
.img-grid{
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
.balloon{
  position:absolute;
  left:30%;
  top:50%;
  width: 6%;
}
.balloon2{
  position:absolute;
  left:60%;
  top:15%;
  width: 6%;
}
```

```html
Resize this area
<div class= "container">
  <div class="image-container">
       <img class="img-grid" src="https://image.ibb.co/hFUHdz/example18.png" />
       
       <img class="balloon" src="https://image.ibb.co/b445WK/tkp_5_balloonpop.png"/>
       <img class="balloon2" src="https://image.ibb.co/b445WK/tkp_5_balloonpop.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="text-container">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/sg6vo8kt/14/) is updated fiddle.

Hope this is what you were looking for. I have set the image width to 8% so as to resize when screen is resized.

```css
.container{
  max-width:600px;
  max-height:400px;
}
.image-container{
  width:70%;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
}
.img-grid{
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
.balloon{
  position:absolute;
  left:30%;
  top:50%;
  width: 8%;
}
.balloon2{
  position:absolute;
  left:60%;
  top:15%;
  width: 8%;
}
```

```html
Resize this area
<div class= "container">
  <div class="image-container">
       <img class="img-grid" src="https://image.ibb.co/hFUHdz/example18.png" />
       
       <img class="balloon" src="https://image.ibb.co/b445WK/tkp_5_balloonpop.png"/>
       <img class="balloon2" src="https://image.ibb.co/b445WK/tkp_5_balloonpop.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="text-container">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually realize that my app has set fix height to container because it has to be full screen(using slick slider kenwheeler for vertical slide) so I am facing problem with different height resolution. Using your fiddle more or less like this: https://jsfiddle.net/archie_lee/sg6vo8kt/22/